# UNION ALL, ORDER BY at the end, invalid identifier, ascending, error message

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting another error message. Please see the below error message. Here I am doing a UNION ALL and I can confirm that this query works without the ORDER BY at the end. However, I do need to order by that column at the end. So, I am not sure how to fix this issue. I even tried removing the second query a. to a1. so they have different aliases. I now know to put ORDER BY at the end of the code when doing a UNION ALL but did not expect to get invalid identifier.

Error Message

```
ORA-00904: "A1"."ID1": invalid identifier
Error at Line: 1 Column: 678
```

Code

```
select a.ID2, a.ID1, cnt, a.*, b.*
from (
select t.*, 
count(distinct ID2) over(partition by ID1) cnt 
from TABLE1 t) a
, TABLE2 b 
where a.cnt > 1
and a.ID2=b.ID2 (+)
and (b.STATUS in ('A','L','P','S') 
or b.DATE1 >= TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
union all
select a1.ID2, a1.ID1, cnt, a1.*, j.*
from (
select t.*, 
count(distinct ID2) over(partition by ID1) cnt 
from TABLE1 t) a1
inner join TABLE2 j
on a1.ID2=j.ID2
inner join SCHEMA1.TABLE3 d
on j.ALTER_ID2=d.ALTER_ID2
where a1.cnt > 1
order by a.ID1 asc, a1.ID1 asc
```

Comment: If you need to order the entire result, wrap the union query with a SELECT * FROM () and then just order that.  Currently you are just trying to order the bottom portion of the UNION and not finding all the right columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY 2, 1 asc -- order by column number`

ORDER BY is executed after the complete SQL is executed.